# System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer threw an exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to access the a class function from another project to unit test project in visual studio. But it's show exception at run time:-

> [System.TypeInitializationException] = {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyDoc.Insert' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My Code given below:

```
SqlTransaction transaction;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbConnString);
con.Open();
transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
Insert insobj = new Insert();**Exception generate here when creating insert class object** 
rowid = insobj.AffiliationInsert("SP_AFFILIATIONS", "testaff", con, transaction);
Assert.AreEqual(54, rowid);

catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Insert.CS

```
 public class Insert
    {
       SqlDataReader dr;
        private static string dbConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
        public string AffiliationInsert(string SP_AFFILIATIONS, string p_AffiliationName, SqlConnection con, SqlTransaction transaction)
        {
            try
            {
                //using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbConnString))
                //{
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = SP_AFFILIATIONS;
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@affilationname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = p_AffiliationName;
                // con.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                string rowid = "";
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    rowid = dr[0].ToString();
                }
                dr.Close();
                dr.Dispose();
                return rowid;
                //    con.Close();
                //}
            }

            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: any exception in your `MyDoc` static constructor?

Comment: Check the (static)constructor/fields assignments of class `MyDoc.Insert`

Comment: AffiliationInsert function is correct on MyDoc project and i don't have insert constructor on Insert Class

Comment: Could you please either post the `MyDoc.Insert` type completely, or at least the static members (and the static constructor if there is one), so we can take a look at it? (Since the `TypeInitializationException` is usually caused by static members of a type)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Seems to be the access to the `ConfigurationManager`... Have you checked your App.config (or Web.config) to make sure the `connectionstring` is present (with exactly that name)?

Comment: Exception is here:-    Insert insobj = new Insert();   when creating Insert class instanse(Object) not in web.config.